# Island Range Hood Not Centered above the Stovetop

Tags: hood, island

He, I'm in the process of doing a small remodel to my kitchen. We took out a half wall that the stovetop is positioned in front of and are converting the wall mount hood to an island. My issue is that the 8" duct for the hood was previously installed for a wall mount so when converting to the island, the new hood is only half over the stovetop and half into the dining room. The duct cannot be adjusted into the kitchen because it is up against a joist in the ceiling. Is anyone aware of any island hoods that have an off-centered duct shaft? I've seen a few photos but cannot identify models or brands.

Thanks!

Comment: `I've seen a few photos but cannot identify models or brands.`  ... post the links to the pictures

Comment: VTC -product recommendations are off topic.